# CriteriaBuilder query with sub-query, single column result, max function and generic types using metamodel

Tags: criteria, metaclass

My objective is to replace an old JPQL query with a generic type-safe helper method using `javax.persistence.metamodel` and `javax.persitence.criteria`.

The query is essentially

```
select * from table 
    where field1 = arg1 
        and field2 = arg2 
        and field3 = (select max (field3) 
                        from table 
                        where field1 = arg1 
                            and field2 = arg2 
                            and field3 <= arg3
                     )
```

Admittedly this is maybe too specialized a query to generalize but I see the need for 2 or 3 other more generic helpers which I can model on this solution.

I have been googling the Criteria documentation (one problem is it's easy to surf a google search result list and mistakenly move from a `javax.persitence` page to a `JBoss Hibernate` page... and they are NOT the same).

I have obviously not found a one-stop shop that tells me all I need to know:

- how to select a single field in a `CriteriaQuery`
- how to structure a subquery in a `CriteriaQuery` `Expression`
- how to write a max aggregate function call using `CriteriaBuilder`
- how to properly use Static Metamodel attributes to specify generic classes in a `CriteriaBuilder` query, when the table being queried has a composite key which is mapped by composite key class (using `@EmbeddedId`)

Answer (score 1):

OK. I already had the answer before I posted the question but I thought it might be useful to publish what I found.

The use case is a CHARGE table that provides CHG_NU values for ranges of product-option-level values. The appropriate
CHG_NU from the table is the one that matches a PROD_CD and OPTION_TYPE and does not exceed the OPTION_LEVEL.

Here's the method I ended up writing (the comments are specific to the above use-case but the code is generic):

```
public static <X, KT, PT, BT, NT extends Number> X findWithUpperLimit (Class<X> rootClass, Class<NT> numericClass,
                                                                SingularAttribute<X, KT> keyAttr, 
                                                                SingularAttribute<KT, PT> arg1Attr, PT arg1Val,
                                                                SingularAttribute<KT, BT> arg2Attr, BT arg2Val,
                                                                SingularAttribute<KT, NT> numericAttr, NT number,
                                                                EntityManager em)
{
    List<X> results;

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder ();

    // set up the query (returns a full record of the CHARGE table)...
    CriteriaQuery<X> cq = cb.createQuery (rootClass);
    // ... and the subquery (returns only the BigDecimal OPT_LEVEL)
    Subquery<NT> sq = cq.subquery (numericClass);

    // set up the root objects for the CHARGE table. Both the query and the subquery are on the same table
    Root<X> root = cq.from (rootClass);
    Root<X> sqRoot = sq.from (rootClass);

    // the query objects and the criteria builder are used to structure the query, 
    // the root objects are used to get metadata from the table to assign table elements to the criteria

    // the subquery gets the closest optLevel to the passed-in number... 
    sq.select (cb.max (sqRoot.get (keyAttr).get (numericAttr)))
                    .where (cb.and 
                            (cb.equal (sqRoot.get (keyAttr).get (arg1Attr), arg1Val),
                             cb.equal (sqRoot.get (keyAttr).get (arg2Attr), arg2Val),
                             cb.le (sqRoot.get (keyAttr).get (numericAttr), number)
                ));

    // ...and the main query matches the passed-in prodCd, optType and the optLevel found by the subquery.
    cq.select (root).where (cb.and (cb.equal (root.get (keyAttr).get (arg1Attr), arg1Val),
                                    cb.equal (root.get (keyAttr).get (arg2Attr), arg2Val),
                                    cb.equal (root.get (keyAttr).get (numericAttr), sq)
                                   ));

    results = em.createQuery (cq).getResultList ();

    return results.size() == 0 ? null : results.get (0);
}
```

This is a code snippet that calls it:

```
Charge charge = DAOHelper.findWithUpperLimit (Charge.class, BigDecimal.class,
                                                Charge_.key,
                                                ChargeKey_.prodCd, invoice.getCharge().getChargeKey().getProdCd(),
                                                ChargeKey_.optType, invoice.getCharge().getChargeKey().getOptType(),
                                                ChargeKey_.optLevel, invoice.getCharge().getChargeKey().getOptType(),
                                                em);
```

and here's the SQL that it generates:

```
select charge0_.OPTION_TYPE_CD as OPTION_1_50_, 
            charge0_.OPTION_LEVEL as OPTION_LEV2_50_, 
            charge0_.PROD_CD as PROD_CD3_50_, 
            charge0_.CHG_NU as CHG_NU4_50_ 
    from CHARGE charge0_ 
        where charge0_.PROD_CD=? 
            and charge0_.OPTION_TYPE_CD=? 
            and charge0_.OPTION_LEVEL=(select max(charge1_.OPTION_LEVEL) 
                                            from CHARGE charge1_ 
                                            where charge1_.PROD_CD=? 
                                                and charge1_.OPTION_TYPE_CD=? 
                                                and charge1_.OPTION_LEVEL<=1358.00
                                          )
```